# get most important nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In my project I need to visualise limited amount of nodes from graph. So for example if my graph have 1 M nodes I need to show 500 nodes. They can't be random nodes without any connections between each other. To illustrate them I need an algorithm which will choose central or important nodes with their neighbors (connected nodes). My questions are

1. Is there ready to use functions in neo4j or apoc for this purpose ?
2. If no is there algorithms I can use ?
3. Does simple `RETURN ... LIMIT 500` do the job ?

Comment: Look into Neo4j's Graph Data Science library and try out different centrality measures, probably starting with something like PageRank.
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/introduction/

Comment: Thank you, I compared pageRank with degreeCentrality and pageRank is better for my purpose. Although using just LIMIT is working good too, It doesn't seem like it returns random nodes